# Reference request: given a divisor d of N, how quickly can I obtain the largest factor of N coprime to d?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms, reference-request

This is quite likely to be a solved problem, perhaps even a standard exercise. However, being a non-[number theorist], I don't know where to look. A quick perusal of the basic starting references of Google, CLRS, and Bach+Shallit does not seem to help.

*Problem.* I have an integer *N*, and a divisor *d*. What is a good upper bound on the time required to compute coprime integers *n*<sub>1</sub> and *n*<sub>2</sub> , such that *N* = *n*<sub>1</sub>*n*<sub>2</sub> , and such that *d* divides *n*<sub>1</sub>?

**Actual Question.** What is a good reference for the solution / time requirements for this problem?

*Solution to problem.* As I'm aware that this may also be an exercise in some number-theory class, I'll outline a very reasonable iterative approach as a good-faith gesture.

Define sequences  *x<sub>j</sub>* , *y<sub>j</sub>* , and *g<sub>j</sub>* by the recurrences

$\begin{align}
\quad x_1 =& d & \quad && x_{j+1} =& x_j g_j \\\\
y_1 =& N/d   &&& y_{j+1} =& y_j / g_j \\\\
g_1 =& \gcd(x_1, y_1) &&& g_{j+1} =& \gcd(x_j, y_j) 
\end{align}$

which eventually converge. When this occurs (i.e. for *j* sufficiently large that *g<sub>j</sub>* = 1), we may let *n*<sub>1</sub> = *x<sub>j</sub>* and *n*<sub>2</sub> = *y<sub>j</sub>* .

Note that for any *j* such that *x<sub>j</sub>* ≥ *y<sub>j</sub>* , we may show without too much difficulty that *g*<sub>*j*+1</sub> = 1; so the last few iterations take time O( log(*N*)<sup>2</sup> ), and the time required for the preceding iterations increases monotonically with *x<sub>j</sub>* . Considering the prime-power decompositions of *x<sub>j</sub>* and of *N*, we may note that the exponent of the maximal power of each prime *p* dividing *x<sub>j</sub>* doubles with each succesive iteration, until it saturates the exponent of the maximal power of *p* which divides *N*. Thus, the number of iterations required will be bounded above by something like log log(*N*). The cumulative run-time of all but the last few iterations depends exponentially on the number of iterations; one can then bound the time required for all but the last few iterations by something like O( log(*N*)<sup>2</sup> ) again.
This is then an upper bound for the whole procedure.

**Remark.** I doubt that one can do better than the upper bound of O( log(*N*)<sup>2</sup> ) above. I also doubt that I'm the first person to solve this problem, and I'd rather not clutter up a paper describing this solution if I can cite another paper instead.

Comment: There's a chance that some small prime will divide d once and N lots of times. Maybe it would be better to raise d to some huge power mod N first?

Comment: @Kevin: This is essentially the approach suggested by Robin, below. --- In my approach outlined above, the exponent of that prime in the divisor x_j will increase at an exponential rate, corresponding roughly to repeated squaring; the same holds for each prime factor, except that the exponents saturate at the largest powers dividing N. So my approach is really like a somewhat more cumbersome version of the same thing, in which modular arithmetic is needlessly avoided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at these [papers](http://cr.yp.to/coprimes.html) from Dan Bernstein. It's not quite what you are looking for, but he does even more than you need in time $n(\lg n)^{2+o(1)}$ where $n$ = number of bits of $N\cdot d$ (one of the elements of the coprime base will be $n_2$). Maybe your problem can be solved even faster than that.

Comment: +1 I didn't make the connection between coprime bases and my problem (which is obvious in retrospect), but the ability to factor into a coprime basis quickly is also excellent. I'm reading through this now.

Comment: I've asked [a follow-up question](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3393/reference-request-a-more-complete-faster-factorization-into-coprimes) on CS-Theory, about if there is a more complete version of Bernstein's draft "Faster factorization into coprimes". Interesting articles, thanks again.

Comment: @Niel: You're welcome! And good luck with your question at cstheory!

Answer (score 4):

Another approach would be to take the gcd of $N$ and a large power $p^k$
of $p$. This would give $n_1$. In a worst case scenario, $k$ could be $\lg N$,
but usually you wouldn't need anything this big. You save time by computing
$a\equiv p^k$ (mod $N$) and then computing $\gcd(a,N)$ by the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: +1 Nice approach! Much simpler to bound than my approach above, if one uses non-naive multiplication algorithms. (Which I neglected to consider.)